# How to get the random http port in Bean initialization code in a spring boot web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpserver

I've got a Spring Boot application where I set the http port to random (0) in the settings.
I've got a component in the application that fetches the port in a method:

```
@Autowired
private ServletWebServerApplicationContext webServerAppCtxt;

public void doWork() {
    int localHttpServerPort = webServerAppCtxt.getWebServer().getPort();
```

However, when I try to execute the same code in Bean initializer:

```
@Bean
public IMyBean myBean(ServletWebServerApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    int localHttpServerPort = applicationContext.getWebServer().getPort();
```

the localHttpServer port is always 8080, so using random port doesn't work.
My question is, is it possible to make sure that the Server/Servercontext is fully initialized BEFORE the bean initializer method is called so that using a random port could be already retrieved in the bean initializer?

Answer (score 0):

You can define it like this in the configuration file

```yaml
server:
  port: ${random.int(1000,9999)}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

String port = environment.getProperty("server.port");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.